# How to optimize h.264 to play it on every possible device

Tags: encoding, mp4, h.264

I coding videos in MP4 for my windows phone, but now I want to be sure that this videos will be played on every mobile device possible, so question is: What the best unified settings for H.264 codec I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every device supports every resolution or framerate, so those aspects are outside of H.264 encoding parameters. That said, a framerate of 30 fps or under, and a resolution of 480p or smaller should be safe for most devices currently in use.

As for H.264 encoding, Baseline profile, and a level of 3.x is sufficient. You should only need to specify the profile.